# Tricky Background Colors: Possible with CSS?

Tags: css, background-color

How can I get to this:

```
  -------------------------------
  |                     |       |
  |                     |       |
  |                     |       |
  |                     |       |
  |                     |       |
  |                     |       |
  -------------------------------
<- #fff                 | #ddd  ->
```

I've got a fixed width centered div, two columns. The left one has a white background, the right one's background is grey. So far so good.

Now I want the background colors extend to the page margin. As sketched above. Is this somehow possible?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: What do you mean by 'the page margin'? There's no such thing in an HTML document - you'll have to add extra elements above and/or below your existing ones and colour them to match.

Comment: I just want the background colors to extend to the full browser window width...

Comment: Then stretch your elements to the full browser width, or use a reeaaalllyyy wide bg image on the body.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand correctly what you seek, you do not want the background the same color as the div's, but you want it to align with the "joint" not matter the width of the window even though the content div's are part of a centered, fixed width container. The following solution seems to work thought not tested in all browsers (took me a few hours to solve).

HTML:

```
<div class="leftBkg">   
    <div class="content">   
        <div class="left"></div>        
        <div class="right"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="rightBkg"></div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
body {
    background-color: cyan; /* just to see no body bkg is showing */
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}
.content {
    width: 700px; 
    margin: 50px auto; /* top and bottom margin for illustration */
    position: relative;
    z-index: 1; /* lift it above right background */
    overflow: auto;
}
.left {
    width: 500px; 
    background-color: #ff0000; 
    float: left; 
    min-height: 1000px; /* just for demo */
}
.right {
    width: 200px;  
    background-color: #0000ff; 
    float: left; 
    min-height: 1000px; /* just for demo */

}
.rightBkg {
    background-color: #dddddd;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 50%;
    right: 0;
    margin-left: 150px; /* (left column width - right column width) / 2 */
    z-index: 0; /* keep it below content */
}
.leftBkg {
    background-color: #ffffff;      
    position: absolute;     
    left: 0;
    width: 100%; /* make it window size */ 
    min-width: 700px; /* same as content width to keep backgrounds from scrolling horizontal on narrow window */
    min-height: 100%; /* make sure it always covers screen height */
    overflow: auto;
}
```

Comment: Great. Glad I interpreted correctly and found a solution that worked for you.

Answer (score 1):

I would have a content div with 100%, containing a left and right column, that are centered and have the background colors.

Example here: 
http://jsfiddle.net/MSuJT/

---

Comment: Sorry - refresh to get the new link.

Answer (score 0):

Make the centered div width 100%, then put a div inside to contain the content.

Comment: I don't see how this helps to get everything left of the fixed width container white and everything right of it grey? Or am I getting something wrong?

Comment: The fixed width is inside the other one, so it's centred on top.